# Lua function returning tuple of values

Tags: python, lua, torch

I have seen the following python code:

```
W_grads, _ = backward_gradient(X, S, grad_out, wRec)
```

And in the function backward_gradient, I have the following return statement:

```
return (wx_grad, wRec_grad), grad_over_time
```

How can I return a tuple similar to the above in lua so that it can be implemented in torch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a table for that.

```
return {wx_grad, wRec_grad}, grad_over_time
```

Refer to for more information http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1

> Tables are the sole data-structuring mechanism in Lua; they can be
>   used to represent ordinary arrays, sequences, symbol tables, sets,
>   records, graphs, trees, etc. To represent records, Lua uses the field
>   name as an index. The language supports this representation by
>   providing a.name as syntactic sugar for a["name"]. There are several
>   convenient ways to create tables in Lua (see §3.4.9).

Answer (score 1):

Return a table:

```
return {wx_grad, wRec_grad}, grad_over_time
```

Then access `W_grads[1]` and `W_grads[2]`.